# Postgres connection pooling in django

Tags: django, postgresql

i'm developing a Django application with Postgres Database and without ORM(using raw sql and psycopg2).
how to use connection pooling in this case?  i mean if a webserver like heroku creates an instance of django for each Httprequest how connection pooling should be implemented in this case? where should i put settings of connection pooling in application?

Answer (score 0):

Django core does not implement connection pooling ( it was design decision as pgbouncer does it perfectly), if you need it you should opt to use pgbouncer

Heroku docs regarding [PgBouncer](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections#limit-connections-with-pgbouncer)